# How to create a snort rule to detect a website?

Tags: snort

I am trying to create a snort rule where it will detect if the browser goes to a certain website.

alert tcp any any -> any any (content:"youtube.com"; msg: "Going to youtube"; sid:1000001; rev:1)

The problem is the snort rule is not picking up anything.

Comment: The following local rule worked for me: alert tcp any any <> any any (content:"youtube.com";sid:361000000;rev:1;msg:"youtube.com  detected";) I see the alert if I curl www.youtube.com.